# How to handle edge cases in creation of an EFS resource on AWS, using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-efs

I'm creating AWS Elastic File System resources using [the boto3 SDK](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/efs.html).

In the boto3 docs for EFS (linked above), there are no waiters (unlike for other actions such as launching EC2 instances). So I can't call a waiter to hold execution until the resource is created, and have to write my own. There are also a bunch of edge cases that spring to mind, and I can't find examples that handle them.

```
client = # Attach credentials and create an efs boto3 client

def find_or_create_file_system(self, a_token):

    fs = self.client.create_file_system(CreationToken=a_token, PerformanceMode='generalPurpose')
    # Returns either:
    # {
    #     'OwnerId': 'string',
    #     'CreationToken': 'string',
    #     'FileSystemId': 'string',
    #     'CreationTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    #     'LifeCycleState': 'creating'|'available'|'deleting'|'deleted',
    #     'Name': 'string',
    #     'NumberOfMountTargets': 123,
    #     'SizeInBytes': {
    #         'Value': 123,
    #         'Timestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    #     },
    #     'PerformanceMode': 'generalPurpose'|'maxIO'
    # }

    # Or, if an FS is available with that creation token already, the above returns 
    # an error. According to boto3 docs, the error will contain the existing fs id. 
    # Is this an error I need to manage with try/catch? What is the syntax to get 
    # the id out of the error?
    if there_is_an_error
        # EFS already exists
        if fs['LifeCycleState'] == 'creating'
            # Need to wait until it's created then return its id
        elif fs['LifeCycleState'] != 'available'
            # It is being / has been deleted.
            # What now? Is that token never usable again? Does it eventually disappear so I can reuse it? How long do I have to wait before recreating it?

    #  Wait until available
    fs_desc = self.client.describe_file_systems(FileSystemId=fs.id)

    # TODO figure out whether there's a waiter for this
    while fs_desc['FileSystems'][0]['LifeCycleState'] == 'creating':
        time.sleep(5)
        fs_desc.update() # Updates metadata
        print("EFS state: {0}".format(fs_desc['FileSystems'][0]['LifeCycleState']))

    return fs.id
```

**Question 1** Am I correct that I have to write my own waiter? Could I hijack/repurpose a waiter from other elsewhere in the API, or are there undocumented waiters?

**Question 2** How do I catch the error that occurs when an instance with that token already exists? And how do I get the id out of the error message to handle that case?

**Question 3** Can tokens be reused once a file system is deleted (i.e. does AWS eventually clear up, or does that token persist)?

*The reason I ask Q3 is that there are no Filter={} options in client.describe_file_systems(). So at present, I'm using a token containing a simple unique text handle, to create and later retrieve an EFS unique to a customer. I could use a random UUID token, then tag with organisation name... but can't retrieve based on tag!!!*

**Question 4** Is that while loop robust? i.e. is there a circumstance in which AWS will perpetually return 'creating' status (which would throw me into an infinite loop)?

Thanks for any help!